# Ширина страницы сжимается на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css, joomla

Не могу понять почему при ширине экрана от 750px и меньше, сайт начинает сжиматься к левому краю...
http://severschool10.ru/

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83)

Comment: Креативный дизайн

Comment: скрин проблемы выложи

Comment: [график работы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6TN8.png) привлек внимание

Comment: @Alex78191, где вы график работы увидели?О_о

Comment: @MedvedevDev на другой странице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если кратко, position: absolute

```
  html {
    font-family: Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 110%;
    line-height: 1.61em;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    color: #212121;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Подробнее:

> position: absolute; Указывает, что элемент абсолютно позиционирован,
>   при этом другие элементы отображаются на веб-странице словно абсолютно
>   позиционированного элемента и нет.

Здесь кстати не обязательно именно html делать так. Можно все что внутри body, обернуть в div#main, и сделать ему позиционирование.
Там у тебя список Пагинации выезжал за html, и его ущемлял.

Не могу быть 100% прав, но имхо, html всегда 100% ширины экрана, а список вылазил за него и делал ширину экрана > 100%.
Пример: Ширина списка 150%, html 100% вот те 50% светились сбоку.

Comment: покажу разницу на скриншотах, я не заметил отличий

Comment: vertical-align убрал, не помогает....

Comment: теперь гуд, пробуй

Comment: Так бы сразу написал

Comment: @Alex78191 затупил ))

Comment: "position: absolute" помог, спасибо! А можно кратко объяснить, почему он помог?